# (Pathlib) Root + 'foldername' throwing TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'

Tags: python, selenium

My code is in a folder and I've created a folder named "Backups" within the root folder where my code is. When I try "dst = root / 'Backup'+email", it ends up giving me the unsupported operand for windowspath and str. I'm not sure why that is happening? I was able to successfully use root / in another function of mine and it worked fine. How do I fix this error?

```
from pathlib import Path

root = Path(__file__).parent

  def myfunction(self, email): #chrome webdriver, download location will be 'dst'
        dst = root / 'Backups'+email
        Path(dst).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        prefs = {"download.default_directory" : dst}


def Move(self, email): #this code works fine, I need move files from Backup folder to Backupzip

        source_dir = root /'Backup/'+email+'/'
        dst = root / 'BackUpZip/'+email
        Path(dst).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        dst=dst+'/'
        files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_dir, "*.zip"))
        for file in files:
             if os.path.isfile(file):
                shutil.copy(file, dst)
                os.remove(file)
```

Updated my code with a solution given in comments. New error shows.

```
        dst = root / ('Backups\\'+ email)
        Path(dst).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        prefs = {"download.default_directory" : dst}
```

TypeError: Object of type WindowsPath is not JSON serializable

Comment: It's doing the `root / Backups` operation first.  The result of that operation is a `WindowsPath` object, and you can't append a plain string to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your code, due to operation precedence, is actually building up the path with backups, and then trying to concatenate the path with email, which gives you the error.
To fix this, you must group backups and email in parenteses, so that that expression is built first and you can build the path with the final concatenated string

```
from pathlib import Path

root = Path(__file__).parent

 def myfunction(self, email): #chrome webdriver, download location will be 'dst'
        dst = root / ('Backups'+email)
        Path(dst).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        prefs = {"download.default_directory" : dst}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This fixed one of my problems. Now the folder gets created in the root dir when I run my script but before selenium can launch, I get this new error:

TypeError: Object of type WindowsPath is not JSON serializable

How do I fix this?

Comment: To fix  this, you could cast the windowPath to a string with str(root) wherever you're trying to serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dst=os.path.join(root, ('Backups\\'+email))
```

This fixed my issue.